# Custom Post Type categories page/template

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a Custom Post Type that has a series of different categories that need their own landing page. Right now I have gone through [WP Post Type Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates) but I still cannot get the category page to show up. Right now the CPT category pages just 404.

I have tried to do the following:

1. Register post type archives based off [this](http://xplus3.net/2010/08/08/archives-for-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/).
2. Create archive template files using **archive-teams.php** and **archive-team.php**.
3. Tried using **category-teams.php** and **category-team.php**.
4. Flushed permalinks 1 Million times.

Here is how I am registering the post type and taxonomy:

```
add_action('init', 'create_team');
function create_team() {

  register_taxonomy(
    'teams',
    array(),
    array(
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'labels' => array
      (
        'name' => _x('Teams', 'taxonomy general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Team', 'taxonomy singular name')
      ),
      'show_ui' => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true,
      'query_var' => 'team',
      'rewrite' => array(
          'slug' => 'our-team',
      ),
    )
  );

  register_post_type(
    'team',
    array(
      'labels' => array
      (
        'name' => _x('Team Members', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Team Member', 'post type singular name')
      ),
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
      'public' => true,
      'rewrite' => array
      (
        'slug' => 'our-team/%teams%',
        'with_front' => false
      ),
      'query_var' => 'team',
      'has_archive' => 'team',
      'taxonomies' => array( 'teams','category','post_tag' ),
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: What you need in this..

Comment: What's problem are you facing?

Comment: @Mr.HK the categories template is not working/showing up and gets a 404.

Comment: Okay wi;ll check it, And let you know

Comment: What links are you using and what are you expecting? The template should be "taxonomy-teams.php" not "category-teams.php"

Answer (score 0):

You should try archive-$customposttype.php for editing the archive file, including category page template for custom post types. You can read more here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. I am sure this will work:-

1. In your `functions.php`, put this line of code under `add_action` hook:-

```php
register_taxonomy('category_events', array('events'), array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Events','show_admin_column' => true, 'singular_label' => 'Events', 'rewrite' => true));
```

You can name your slugs accordingly.

2. Name your Taxonomy file like this:

`taxonomy-{slug}.php` # Where slug is the name of the first argument provided in the above code snippet.

3. refresh the settings by going to **Settings > Permalinks**.

And boom you have your custom taxonomy up and ready.

Credits and Thanks to Harun Mansuri(***) for helping me with this solution

Comment: Note that people you are trying to say thanks to are unlikely to appreciate having their contact info published here. That email address is now probably rendered unuseable.

Comment: Harun Mansuri is actually a co-worker and my senior. We came up with this solution together.

Comment: Uh oh. You trashed your bosses email address. Sorry to hear that. Hope he will be lenient with you.